# UILabel and UITextView not correctly aligned

Tags: swift3, uilabel, ios-autolayout

I do have a UILabel and UITextView above each other, left aligned with Auto Layout. But it looks like this:

[image]

What's the best way to correctly align these?

Answer (score 3):

The most easy way of doing this is to set content inset directly.

```
textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4,-4,0,0)
```

And the result looks like

[image]